# Remove non-GtkListBoxRow parent from GtkListBox

Tags: python, gtk

Just a quick note about something I have encountered recently. I used python, but I guess, it applies for other languages as well.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
listbox = Gtk.ListBox()
somewidget = Gtk.Somewidget()
win.add(listbox)

listbox.insert(somewidget -1)
listbox.remove(somewidget)  #ERROR
```

This is a GtkListBox, filled with an item not of type GtkListBoxRow. When attempting to remove it from the GtkListBox, it gives me the following:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_remove: assertion 'gtk_widget_get_parent (widget) == GTK_WIDGET (container) || GTK_IS_ASSISTANT (container) || GTK_IS_ACTION_BAR (container) || GTK_IS_POPOVER_MENU (container)' failed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that GtkListBox must only have children of type GtkListBoxRow. (see [GTK doc](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListBox.html#GtkListBoxRow)) So, when trying to insert another widget, there is automatically added a GtkListBoxRow widget inbetween:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|                                   |
| GtkListBox                        |
|  +                                |
|  +---> GtkListBoxRow (auto-added) |
|         +                         |
|         +---> Gtksomewidget       |
|                                   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Gtk will fail if you try to remove your own widget, because it wants the direct children of your ListBox. So instead of using

```
listbox.remove(somewidget)
```

type

```
listbox.remove(somewidget.get_parent())
```